# Using SNMP to monitor Qnap Volume Usage

Tags: snmp, mib

I would like to use SNMP to monitor drive usage on a NAS. It's a Qnap TS-859U+.

I'm not sure how to use the MIB to my advantage in recognizing the correct OID's to query the right object instance.

How would I get the correct OID to query, and how would I know what queries the device supports.

I downloaded a MIB browser, iReasoning, but not sure where to look in the MIB tree. I also have the Qnap MIB.

I just need to know from the 3 volumes, what's the Available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should look if Qnap supports the UCD MIBs, like dskTable. This is likely. If not, you should look into the Qnap MIB you downloaded in order to find something similar. Open it, it's a text file, and read it. If you'll find something that looks suitable, place the Qnap MIB to the place your snmpwalk recognizes, add this MIB to the snmpwalk configuration (usually the snmp.conf file) and then query Qnap for this oid. Upon success, you can also translate the oid to numeric form with snmptranslate and use it without actual MIB file.